# Twenty sixteen - full height

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, theme-twenty-sixteen

I want the twenty sixteen theme to "fill up" the height even if the page is empty. So.. If the content does not fill it up, it will be minimum full height.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please start of by visiting [ask] and reading all the question related stuff in [help]

Comment: This is off-topic here as it purely relates to css. You can get more detailed answers from other Stack Exchange sites(eg: Stack Overflow) for this these type of problems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know why you wanna do that, but..

We can use `min-height` with `vh` (view port height) unit for this. Setting height of the page to `100vh` means we are saying the page to fill the full view port height.

```
.site {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

But this doesn't work well with iOS7. So work around is.

```
/** 
 * iPad with portrait orientation.
 */
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){
  .site {
    min-height: 1024px;
  }
}

/** 
 * iPad with landscape orientation.
 */
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
  .site {
    min-height: 768px;
  }
}

/**
 * iPhone 5
 * You can also target devices with aspect ratio.
 */
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
  .site {
    min-height: 500px;
  }
}
```

**References:**

[Can i use :](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

[Work around by pburtchaell](https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587)

Comment: Why down vote ? May i know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Of course. Bad mouse behavior. Click by mistake. Did not notice that. Corrected now. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Guys! who ever is down voting , i request you to comment  so that i won't repeat if it's anything is wrong from my side.

Comment: @Supremelink , it's not you who down voted, some else did :(

Comment: @bravokeyl I did not downvote but you want to know why people are down voting because this is off-topic and down voting is normal on off-topic questions/answers.

Comment: @Sumit, thanks for the input , i thought the same reason.